# How do I create links(or pass any other html/jsx) into the label of the Material-UI <Checkbox ... label="string"/> component

Tags: material-ui

I'm looking for insight on how to pass custom jsx into the label of the Checkbox component.

```
<Checkbox
    label="I accept the Terms of Use & Privacy Policy"
/>
```

Ideally what would render as the label is "I accept the [Terms of Use] & [Privacy Policy]" where the items inside the brackets are links.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can pass in other jsx nodes into the label property. In this example I am using the React Router link but you could of course use an anchor element.

```
<Checkbox
  label={
   <div>
      <span>I accept the </span>
      <Link to={'/terms'}>terms of use</Link>
      <span> and </span>
      <Link to={'/privacy'}>privacy policy</Link>
   </div>
   }
 />
```

Comment: Jeroen, This was exactly the solution I was looking for. Both methods you suggested worked. The documentation on Material-UI's site is pretty sparse in terms of doing this on various components so you've saved me so much time and effort! Thanks for answering!

Comment: @michaelmuxica except the links are not clickable, right ?

Comment: They are/should be clickable. Did you try this and it didn't work?

Comment: Good answer. Depending on your needs, you can also simplify by replacing <div></div> with the React fragment tag <></>

Comment: does it work with Typescript? I tried this and it's complaining that only string is assignable to label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use html in the label property. But you'll have a problem : the component is "covered" by a transparent input which will handle every click. So links or onClicks won't work. Before the library developers resolve the problem, you can use :

```
<Checkbox id={uniqueId}
      labelStyle={{ zIndex: 3 }}
      label={(
                <label htmlFor={uniqueId}>
                          blah blah
                          <span onClick={this.myAction}>yeah</span>
                          <a>...</a>
                </label>
      )}/>
```

Details here => https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5364

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="demo_form.php">
I accept the Terms of Use & Privacy Policy
<input type="Checkbox" name="terms">
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

demo_form.php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["terms"]) . '!';
?>
```

Comment: Jeffrey, this question was specifically related to the use of the React.js based Material-UI. Not PHP. Thank you for trying to help however.